Single noun for what is being emphasised?
Is there a single noun that means "what is being emphasised", analogous to say "subtrahend", "multiplicand", "addend" for what is being subtracted, multiplied, or added?
Example:

In this poem, the use of the word X suggests adoration of the [required word here]".


Adoration of the target?

I'm surprised there's not a technical word cognate with emphasis itself.

Is the meaning: adoration of what is being emphasized? If that is the meaning, the question does not contain enough information.

No, the meaning is not necessarily adoration. I am interested in a single word for "what is being emphasised", i.e. the object of emphasis. The example is just an example. It might be something that is simply being brought into sharp focus, or differentiated from other stuff, without being adored. Just so long as it's being emphasised.

Focus, as you said.

Yes, focus is good. But nothing cognate with emphasis?

Have you looked in a dictionary for words with the same root as emphasis? Not that I've found any that fit (or expected to). But 'focus / theme / thrust' would probably work. A noun corresponding to say 'payee' (one who is being paid) probably doesn't exist. There are many such lexical gaps.

“adoration of a word being emphasised”? That seems a strange target of adoration.

You may want to be specific -- either in the question here, or your wider essay -- about what you believe is being emphasised. Different readers can regard the same art and come to wildly different opinions on what is being emphasised! And it may open up other approaches to describing a very nebulous thing...

I think subject or object fit the bill.

One part of the problem may be a difference between words derived from Latin and from Greek.  the '-and' and '-end' endings are all attached to stems of verbs derived from Latin.  the '-ndum' ending added to the Latin verb 'multiplico' (I multiply) turns the word into a gerundive.  The gerundive is the adjectival equivalent to the gerund, and expresses necessity.  So 'Summa multiplicanda est' would mean 'the sum (total) must be multiplied.  So strictly speaking the multiplicand refers to the thing to be (or that must be) multiplied.
Correspondingly, the subtrahend ('end' rather than 'and' because subtraho is 3rd conjugation) is a shortening of subtrahendum (to be / that must be subtracted) and addend is short for addendum (to be / that must be) added.
The thing is, emphasise is not derived from Latin but from Greek and Greek does not work that way.  It has no gerund or shaping of verbs that would make the addition of -'endum' or '-andum' look right.  The Greek word for 'emphasis' (emphasis) does not have a cognate verb emphasizo.  The equivalent verb is emphaino.  Either way, the best we could end up with an ugly botched crossbreed, 'emphasizend' or 'emphasizand'.  There is, of course, no law against trying it and (who knows?) it could catch on.  But so far it has not.

Minor correction putting ending of the outside the bracket.

You can use emphasized/emphasised itself as a   nominalized adjective as it would come after the definite article the in your example sentence. It is similar to the rich, the poor but this usage of emphasized as an adjectival noun would be rare or rather poetic.

In this poem, the use of the word X suggests adoration of the emphasized.

I don't believe there is a noun cognate of emphasis that specifically denotes 'what is being emphasized.' Depending on the context, other nouns might be more appropriate, or it might be better not to limit oneself to a single word.
On a side note, one could coin emphasisee/emphasizee with the -ee suffix (similar to examinee, employee, respondee etc.) but it sounds off and it is unnecessary.

It’s not a cognate of emphasis, but if you can tolerate, say, a degree or two of separation from Kevin Bacon, then focus might work.
It’s a “light” thing. Here’s a rough path:

emphasis . . . < ancient Greek ἔμϕασις outward appearance, reflection . . . (see phasis n.)
phasis . . . < post-classical Latin phasis (late 4th or early 5th cent.) or its etymon ancient Greek ϕάσις appearance, in Hellenistic Greek also phase < ϕα-, ablaut variant of the stem of ϕαίνειν to bring to light . . .
focus . . . < classical Latin focus hearth, fireplace . . .  Notes: Kepler writes of rays emanating from a
single point being reflected . . . This suggests that the ‘focus’ of a
conic section was likened to a source of light, i.e. a hearth with a
fire burning in it.
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login
required)

So:

In this poem, the use of the word X suggests adoration of its focus.

See also Etymonline: emphasis and focus
